# How can I alter a square image into a circular one in Sketch?

Tags: images, shapes, sketch-app

I want to take a rectangular image in Sketch and give it a circle/radius style.

For example:

[image]

Comment: So... you want to put a square peg in a round hole?

Comment: Do you mind letting us know what you have tried?

Comment: @ale is the one that I ended up using. Worked well!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's actually quite easy. There are two ways to do it:

### 1. Use a Mask

Best way IMHO, as it gives you more flexibility / editing options.

1. Import your image:

   [image: Import]
2. Draw a circle that will mask your image:

   [image: Mask]
3. Move the circle *behind* the bitmap using the `Backward` toolbar icon:

   [image: Back]
4. Use the circle to mask the bitmap, by selecting it and choosing `Layer › Use as Mask` from the menu:

   [image: Mask]
5. Ta-da!

   [image: Done]
6. As an extra step, you can group your bitmap and the circle mask, to stop the circle from masking other shapes:

   [image: Group]
7. To add a border: add another circle shape placed above the masked image.

---

### 2. Use a pattern fill

1. Draw the circle where you want your image to appear:

   [image: Circle]
2. `Select Fill › Pattern Fill` in the inspector:

   [image: Pattern]
3. Click `Choose Image…` and select your bitmap:

   [image: Bitmap]
4. Set the fill options to `Fill` in the drop down:

   [image: Fill]
5. Add a border to the circle as you normally would.
6. Ta-da!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

you can use a masking method through Photoshop.

Here are the steps, I will use a sample rectangular image.

1* Add your rectangular image in Photoshop, place it inside a new document and it will create a new layer just for the image.

[image: Rectangular image of a starry sky, as you can see there is a white background layer underneath it.]

2* Create a circular shape to your desired size using the circle tool, it will create a layer for the object and the layer will be placed on top of the rectangular picture.

[image: Circle object on top of rectangular image layer]

3* Now place the layer of the circle underneath the rectangular image layer. Then click the layer of the rectangular image, right-click and choose create clipping mask.

[image: right-click on the layer of the rectangular image and choose create clipping mask. make sure that layer is on top of the circle object]

4* at this point, you can drag around the rectangular image layer to fit the circle. you can adjust what part of the rectangular image the circle should capture.
[image: drag around the rectangular image layer to fit the circle]

5* once you are happy with the position of the image in the circle, you can select both layers and merge them together to create the circular image. You can either right-click after choosing both layers and choose merge layers or use the shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> if you are using Windows.

[image: select both layers and merge them together]

[image: After you merge them, the layer should look like this, only containing the new circular image.]

6* Lastly, you can add effects such as strokes or drop shadows using the effect button at the bottom of the layers panel. it should have the symbol `fx` on it. Choose stroke, and you can add a stroke of any color you like to your new circular image.

[image: use the effect button at the bottom of the layers panel to create any effect such as strokes or drop-shadows]

[image: adjust the stroke sizes that you like]

[image: final result should look like this, I just used a green color stroke to show what the stroke would look like since my background color layer is white.]

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think the OP asks for a solution in Sketch.

Comment: While this might help someone in Photoshop please understand that your answer could be downvoted because the OP asked for it in Sketch.

Answer (score 1):

This is an idea how to approach the problem differently. Do not clip nor mask, but transform the image to fit in circular space. You need a plugin that transforms from rectangular to polar coordinates:

[image]